# Multipart post of xlsx get corrupted via HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data, xlsx

I am trying to post xlsx file via HTTPUrlconnection, on receiving end I got the file but while opening it in MS Excel its saying that file is corrupted and repairing required . My code snippet for multipart post

```
class MultipartUtility {
        private  final Logger log = getLogger(MultipartUtility.class.getName());
        private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
        private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
        private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 1500000;
        private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 1000000;
        private final HttpURLConnection connection;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;
        private final PrintWriter writer;
        private final String boundary;
        // for log formatting only
        private final URL url;
        private final long start;

        public MultipartUtility(final String strUrl) throws IOException {
            start = currentTimeMillis();
            URL url  = new URL(strUrl);
            this.url = url;
            boundary = "---------------------------" + currentTimeMillis();
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, CHARSET),true);
        }
        public void addFilePart(final String  filePath)throws IOException {
            String fieldName = "content";
            File uploadFile = new File(filePath);
            final String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
            writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF)
                    .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"")
                    .append(fieldName).append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName)
                    .append("\"").append(CRLF).append("Content-Type: ")
                    .append(guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(CRLF)
                    .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF)
                    .append(CRLF);

            writer.flush();
            outputStream.flush();
            try (final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);) {
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
            }
            writer.append(CRLF);
        }


        public HashMap<Object, Object> finish() throws IOException {
            writer.append(CRLF).append("--").append(boundary).append("--").append(CRLF);
            writer.close();

            final int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (status != HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(format("{0} failed with HTTP status: {1}",url, status));
            }
            try (final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String sResponse;
                StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseBuilder = responseBuilder.append(sResponse);
                }
                HashMap respMap = new HashMap();
                respMap.put("RESP_MSG", responseBuilder.toString());
                respMap.put("RESP_CODE", status);
                respMap.put("RESP_SIZE", responseBuilder.toString().length());
                log.log(INFO,format("{0} took {4} ms", url,(currentTimeMillis() - start)));
                log.log(INFO,"status::::::"+status);
                return respMap;
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your code and was able to successfully upload file from java program.
The problem you reported is i guess due to content-type of the file. If you try to upload .xlsx (MS Excel 2007) it deforms the data and need to recover before we read uploaded file.

If you try to upload .xls file, it uploads properly without any deform and MS excel open this file without any warning/error.

So i would suggest to play around 
writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + "application/x-excel")

to find the correct content-type refer to : 
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/481262/contentplustypeplusforplusxlsxplusfile

best of luck

Comment: Your given work around is working fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your **addFilePart** method, in the end, you are appending "**writer.append(CRLF)**"
when the number of files is one you should not add this at the end because it will add extra 2 bits to you file size you are sending over the network which is causing you xlxs file to get corrupted.

below is the code if you want to add one file or multiple files.
in this, we are appending CRLF(to separate the files) to the writer to all the files except the last one.

```
public void addFilePart(List<String> files) {
    if (nonNull(files) && !files.isEmpty()) {
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        files.forEach(file -> {
            try {
                int i = counter.incrementAndGet();
                this.addFilePart(file); // your add file part method
                if (files.size() != i) {
                    writer.append(CRLF);
                }
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @divyansh.... your suggestion help my project works well....
dont add the CRLF too much at the end of the file writing processs.....